# Determine the object that was clicked in three.js

Tags: three.js

I wish to detect when an object has been clicked. I am generating a page from the three.js editor. It is a brilliant environment.

Following the advice from this post (https://mandemeskel.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/mouse-events-raycasting-with-three-js/)  I ended up with the following code. I have placed a comment where I am having a problem.

```
function mousedown( event ) {
    var scene = this.parent;
    var projector = new THREE.Projector();
    var mouse_vector = new THREE.Vector3(),
    mouse = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 1 },
    ray = new THREE.Raycaster( new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0), new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0) ),
    intersects = []; 
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    mouse_vector.set( mouse.x, mouse.y, mouse.z );

    // How do I get the camera?
    projector.unprojectVector( mouse_vector, camera );

    var direction = mouse_vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize();

    ray.set( camera.position, direction );

    var object =  scene.getObjectByProperty( 'uuid', this.uuid, true );

    intersects = ray.intersectObject( object );

    if( intersects.length ) {
            alert( "hit" );
            event.preventDefault();  
    }
 }
```

I have temporarily fixed the problem by modifying app.js in the published page. By moving the camera variable to be global I got around it, but it is obviously a fudge. Is there any way to access the camera generated by the editor without modifying app.js?

```
var camera;
var APP = {
Player: function () {
```

....

Comment: Your issue refers to `closures` in javascript. You may need to read about it before writing the code you need.

Answer (score 0):

The awesome mrdoob has modified the editor to include a getCamera() call
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7510#issuecomment-153059247
The default camera can now be accessed by

```
var camera = player.getCamera();
```